# CakePHP: Table Organization for types of Posts

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm quite new to CakePHP and I'd like to think I've been getting the gist of it fairly quickly. My question is sort of more in relation to MySQL but I'll bring Cake back into it at the end.

I'm creating a forum/bulletin board sort of application. Currently I have a posts entry in my database that holds the usuals: id, title, body, etc, etc.

**My problem:** I want to implement various different types of 'posts'. Like Photo Posts, Text Posts, Staff Posts, etc (similar to how tumblr organizes its posts). Should I be making separate tables for each type of these posts, like text_posts, photo_posts, etc? OR can I have fields in the regular Post table like "image_url" that if its left empty upon creating, then I have the view interpret it as a text post?

And if I were to create separate tables for each of the different types, I would set all of those different posts in the bulletin board Controller so I can display them in the Bulletin View. But then in the view, how would I have them display in one nice feed based on when they were created? I don't want to have for loops that displays all text posts, all photo posts, etc. I want them to mesh them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you have a problem with inheritence in your database structure.

> Relational databases don't support inheritance

Three possible ways I know off how to solve this problem are:

[1.Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) (One table for all posts, will have a lot of NULL values then.)

[2.Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) (Try to implement inheritance anyway but mapping each object you would create in PHP to a table.)

[3.Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html) (Seperate table for each type of post)

Which solutions is better for you I cannot tell. They each have their advantages and disadvantages.

**Edit: The PHP part**

Though I don't know much about PHP, you could probably do something like this:

If you choose option 3 to store the posts in your database you could still choose introduce the inheritance in PHP. Loop through the parent class objects (Post) and display properties specific to a child (Photo, Text etc.) by checking if it’s an instance of that object type.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Ideally for me I think the Single Table Inheritance would be easiest to implement... Though I'm more wondering if it would be better use of resources to go ahead and split them up rather than having a bunch of PHP if statements sifting through the several null entries every time I display posts. Or would it not really matter?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could create a different table for each and write a view over it.  Unfortunately MySQL does not support instead of trigger that you will need to insert.
Here is an example using sqlite3 that does it.

```
create table PhotoTable (
id     integer not null PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
PhotoName varchar(255),
Camera    varchar(255)
);


create table StaffTable (
  id integer not null PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  StaffName varchar(255)
); 

--- Odd way of seeding AUTOINCREMENT value in SQLite3
insert into StaffTable(StaffName) values('odd');
delete from StaffTable;
update SQLITE_SEQUENCE set seq = 100000 where name ='StaffTable';


create view posts as
select id, 'Photo' as Type, PhotoName, Camera, NULL as StaffName from PhotoTable
union all 
select id, 'Staff' as Type, NULL as PhotoName, NULL as Camera,StaffName from StaffTable;



create trigger postsinsert
instead of insert on posts
for each row
begin
    insert into PhotoTable(PhotoName, Camera) select new.PhotoName, new.Camera where New.Type ='Photo';
    insert into StaffTable(StaffName) select new.StaffName where New.Type = 'Staff';
end;


insert into posts(Type, PhotoName, Camera) values('Photo','photo1','nk');
insert into posts(Type, PhotoName, Camera) values('Photo','photo2','canon');
insert into posts(Type, StaffName) values('Staff', 'spaceghost');
```

and you get the expected result of

```
 select * from posts;
1|Photo|photo1|nk|
2|Photo|photo2|canon|
100001|Staff|||spaceghost
```

Comment: hmm this is something I'll have to consider. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 tables should be better than creating new table for each type.

You can have posts table and post_types table, in posts table you can have post_type_id foreign key, this would help you grow types without having to create a new table each time.

Then in posts table, make the columns as generic as possible, so for example you can have a "value" column which you can be used to save image url or anything else based on the post type.

Also worth considering at this stage is if your post would need to have multiple types, in which case a bridge table would be handy, so one table for posts another for types and third to hold post and type id as foreign keys.